# FB Bot - Adding pages_messaging_subscriptions to existing public bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-app-center

I have an approved Facebook Messenger Bot live and public. Now I have added a subscription functionality to my bot in a development environment and want to integrate it into my live version.

My question is now regarding the review process. As mentioned in the docs, I have to get approved the 'pages_messaging_subscriptions' permission in order to offer subscriptions to the user.

Can I now simply add the subscription functionality to my live version and then start the review process or do I have to start the review process first and after being reviewed successfully I can update my live version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same problem. I just added the subscription permission to my bot and started the review process that it has passed successfully then.